# Direction of friction in non-inertial reference frame?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, friction

> A beetle is moving radially with velocity $\bf{v}$ on a disk rotating with angular velocity $\bf{w}$. The coefficient of friction between the beetle and  the disk is $\mu$. Find the distance $x_0$ from the centre of the disk where beetle will start sliding.

From the reference of a observer sitting at the centre of the disk and rotating with it, the force on beetle is given by $$\mathbf{F'} = N \mathbf{\hat k} +mg (\mathbf{-\hat k}) - \mathbf{f} + mw^2 \mathbf{r} - 2m (\mathbf{w} \times \mathbf{v}) \tag {1}$$

where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector of the beetle, $N$ is the normal force and $\mathbf{f}$ is the frictional force.

---

The direction of frictional force on some object is given by $\dfrac{-\mathbf{u}}{|\mathbf{u}|}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is its velocity. The velocity of the beetle from the frame of the disk is $\mathbf{v}$ but from the frame of ground it is $\mathbf{v_g} = \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w \times r}$.

I am confused whether to take $\mathbf{f} = f  \dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}$ or $\mathbf{f} = f  \dfrac{\mathbf{v_g}}{|\mathbf{v_g}|}$ in $(1)$ ?

Comment: Doesn't friction try to oppose slipping between two surfaces. To determine direction of slipping assume no friction and find the direction of motion and friction acts opposite to it

Comment: @AdityaGarg I think that's an answer! You might flesh it out a bit to specifically address the confusion mentioned in the last question, but your statement is absolutely right.

Comment: I got for the distance $X_{0}=\dfrac {g\cdot \mu }{\omega ^{2}}$ is this result correct?

Comment: @Eli The answer is $x_0 = 1/w^2 \sqrt{\mu^2 g^2 - 4v^2 w^2}$

Comment: @user8277998 thank you, I will see how to get it

Comment: @Eli Tell me too! I can't solve this question. :( I used $\mathbf{F'} = 0$ as the sliding condition but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed that you have to take into account is the relative speed of the bee. Is is this speed who is important in the friction law.

So it is simply the speed you are using in the non inertial frame.

Comment: Just to clarify, $\mathbf{f} = f{\dfrac{\bf v}{| \mathbf{v}|}}$ in equation $(1)$ ?

Comment: Precisely $\overrightarrow{F}=-f\left\| \overrightarrow{N} \right\|\frac{\overrightarrow{v}}{\left\| \overrightarrow{v} \right\|}$